# Refinery extensions model inheritance

Tags: ruby, model, refinerycms

I have an error with STI in refinery extensions. I have two extensions: "reservation_items" and "items".
Now I need table "items" inherit "reservation_items".
I generated two extensions with refinery generator

```
rails generate refinery:engine reservation_item date_from:date date_to:date people_min:integer people_max:integer price_1:float price_2:float price_3:float type:string --skip-frontend
rails g refinery:engine item item_type:integer
```

My model in reservation_items extension:

```
module Refinery
  module ReservationItems
    class ReservationItem extends Refinery::Core::BaseModel
      self.abstract_class = true
      self.table_name = 'refinery_reservation_items'

      attr_accessible :date_from, :date_to, :people_min, :people_max, :price_1, :price_2, :price_3, :type, :position

      validates :type, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
    end
  end
end
```

I changed "items" extension model to:

```
module Refinery
  module Items
    class Item extends Refinery::ReservationItems::ReservationItem

      self.table_name = 'refinery_items'

      attr_accessible :item_type, :position

      # def title was created automatically because you didn't specify a string field
      # when you ran the refinery:engine generator. Refinery CMS.
      def title
        "Override def title in vendor/extensions/items/app/models/refinery/items/item.rb"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I tried too:

```
module Refinery
  module Items
    class Item extends ReservationItem
```

I don't know anymore what I do bad. How I can inherit this two tables?

//please replace word "extends" for "<" in codes.

**RESOLVED:** Class "Item" can not to have "self.table_name"!